# Boxplot - accessing column names with variables

Tags: r, boxplot

How can I access a column by using a variable that contains the name of the column?

Let's assume we have a data frame DF with 3 columns: 
**Var1  Var2  Var3**, where 
Var3 contains numerical data and Var1 as well as Var2 contain a few factors.

We would like to produce 2 boxplots using a temporary variable that contains the name of the column:

```
temp<-"Var3"
boxplot(DF[temp]) #(<--that works).
```

If I use the same method to obtain a boxplot for each factor in Var2, it doesn't:

```
boxplot(DF[temp]~DF$Var2) #(<-- does not work).
```

How can I get this working?

Annotation:
If I use the name "Var3" directly, it does work and shows several boxplots:

`boxplot(DF$Var3~DF$Var2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using double brackets instead of single brackets:

```
tmp1 <- 'Sepal.Width'
tmp2 <- 'Species'
boxplot( iris[[tmp1]] ~ iris[[tmp2]] )
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Before I tried [,[tmp1]] which did not work. Your solution is even easier to carry out and it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this. The `with` statement instructs `boxplot` to look for variables inside `DF`, the `get` statement accesses the object with name `tmp`.

```
with(DF, boxplot(get(tmp) ~ Var2))
```

Here is an illustrative example

```
tmp <- 'wt'
with(mtcars, boxplot(get(tmp) ~ cyl))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Ramnath, thanks a lot for your answer! I especially liked that you give a detailed description on what the different elements in your code are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` to construct the formula, and then convert to a formula for the boxplot call:

```
boxplot(as.formula(paste(temp,"Var2",sep="~")),DF)
```

Comment: It seems there are many different options to perform the task. I tried your solution and it works fine. Very interesting method.